# Getting error while connecting ADLS to Notebook in AML

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting below error while connecting dataset created and registered in AML notebook and which is based on ADLS. When I connect this dataset in designer I am able to visualize the same. Below is the code that I am using. Please let me know the solution if anyone have faced the same error.

#### Examle 1 Import dataset to notebbok

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = 'abcd'
resource_group = 'RGB'
workspace_name = 'DSG'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='abc')
dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

#### Error 1

```
ExecutionError: Could not execute the specified transform.
(Error in getting metadata for path /local/top.txt.
Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with Unknown Error: The operation has timed out..
Last encountered exception thrown after 5 tries.
[The operation has timed out.,The operation has timed out.,The operation has timed out.,The operation has timed out.,The operation has timed out.]
[ServerRequestId:])|session_id=2d67
```

#### Example 2 Import data from datastore to notebook

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Datastore, Dataset

datastore_name = 'abc'
workspace = Workspace.from_config()

datastore = Datastore.get(workspace, datastore_name)
datastore_paths = [(datastore, '/local/top.txt')]
df_ds = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(
    path=datastore_paths, validate=True,
    include_path=False, infer_column_types=True,
    set_column_types=None, separator='\t',
    header=True, partition_format=None
    )

df = df_ds.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

#### Error 2

```
Cannot load any data from the specified path. Make sure the path is accessible.
```

Comment: are you using Data Lake gen1 or gen2?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the initial slash from your path `'local/top.txt'`

`datastore_paths = [(datastore, 'local/top.txt')]`

Answer (score 0):

For your dataset abc, can you visualize/preview the data on ml.azure.com?
Might be due to the fact that your data permission is not set up correctly in ADLS. You need to give permission to the service principal for the file/folder you are access.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control

Data Access Setting on a file in ADLS
[image]